# Laravel many to many relation return empty array or null values

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-8

I have registered successfully records in the pivot table using `sync` adding extra fields.

[image]

I'm trying of retrieve the qualities that belongs to one buyer through `php artisan tinker`, However I'm getting an empty array `[]` or using the web app I got a null array.

```
>>> $buyer = App\Models\Buyer::first();
=> App\Models\Buyer {#4513
     id: 24,
     ruc: "93894383489",
     companyName: "Some XYZ buyer",
     contact: "some contact",
     address: "sadjasdja",
     phone: "903290329",
     email: "test@gmail.com",
     created_at: "2021-08-26 12:40:42",
     updated_at: "2021-08-26 12:40:42",
     deleted_at: null,
   }
>>> $buyer->qualities;
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4491
     all: [],
   }
>>>
```

As we can see in the below image, the Buyer have a register inside the pivot table. However using php artisan tinker I got an empty array or null in the web app:

[image]

This are the relations:

**Model Buyer**

```
public function qualities(){
    
    return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class, 'product_interested',
                                           'quality_id',
                                         'product_id',
                                         'buyer_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Model Quality**

```
public function qualities(){
    //relación muchos a muchos
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quality::class)->using(InterestedProduct::class);
}

public function buyers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class)->using(InterestedProduct::class);
}
```

**Model Product**

```
public function buyers(){
    //relación muchos a muchos
    return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class);
}

public function products(){
    //relación muchos a muchos
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

The next code is about how I regiter a new buyer and his product interested:

```
public function store(createBuyerRequest $request){
        if($request->validated()){
          try{
            //Crear comprador
           $buyer = new Buyer;
           $buyer->ruc = $request->ruc;
           $buyer->companyName = $request->companyName;
           $buyer->contact = $request->contact;
           $buyer->address = $request->address;
           $buyer->phone = $request->phone;
           $buyer->email = $request->email;
           $buyer->save();
           
           $arrayQualitiesIds = $request->get('qualitiesProductCheckbox');
           
            $extra = array_map(function($qualityId) use($request, $buyer){
                return ['quality_id' => $qualityId,
                         'product_id' => $request->product,
                         'buyer_id' => $buyer->id,
                         'color' => $request->color,
                         'humidity' => $request->humidity];
            }, $arrayQualitiesIds);
            //combibar arreglos
            $data = array_combine($arrayQualitiesIds, $extra);
            /*
            dd($data);
            array:1 [▼
            4 => array:3 [▼
              "quality_id" => "4"
              "product_id" => "6"
              "buyer_id" => 19
            ]
          ]
            */
            $buyer->qualities()->sync($data);
            //Redireccionar
            return redirect()->route('admin.buyers.index')
            ->with('status_success','Comprador registrado correctamente!');
          }catch(Exception $e){
               //Redireccionar
               return redirect()->route('admin.buyers.index')
             ->with('cancel','No se pudo registrar el comprador. '.$e->getMessage());
          }
        }
    }
```

And finally this next code is about how I'm trying of get the qualities of one buyer:

```
public function edit($id){
      $buyer = Buyer::findOrFail($id);
      $qualities =  $buyer->qualities()->where('buyer_id','=', $buyer->id)->first();

      dd($qualities);
}
```

This returns null:

[image]

I hope some help from you guys, I will appreciate if you have any ideas for fix this problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you want return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'product_interested', 'buyer_id', 'quality_id');  Then in your loop of quality you can fetch the product id.

Comment: Thanks bro it worked!but, why that order of the foreign keys? `(Quality::class, 'product_interested', 'buyer_id', 'quality_id')->withTimestamps();` and Why should Ignore `product_id`. Thanks

Comment: the docs have this return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');   if you don't use the standard naming. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many towards the bottom of this many-to-many part

Comment: happy coding friend, take care.  (be sure your inverse relationships work as well)  $quality->buyer and such just in case you need them in the future.